# Can the addition of test points affect the quality of high-frequency signals?

Tags: pcb-design, high-frequency

I am designing a high PCB where there are some digital signals with a frequency of 100MHz. What problems will I run into if I add testpoints to those signals?

Comment: It depends what signals those are and how you are going to wire them to test points. Of course the test points will affect the quality of high-frequency signals. The worst case it the signals get distorted so much that the circuit won't work. Without knowing anything more, it is difficult to say if the effect is barely noticeable or very disruptive.

Comment: Are there a guide on what to look out for?

Comment: Most likely there is. Any good guide should warn about stubs, pad capacitance and other high speed PCB design techniques. It will also matter if the 100 MHz is a sine wave, or a square wave, because a 100 MHz square wave would have an enormous bandwidth requirement maybe well into the GHz region, depending on the slew rate. If you would tell what the 100 MHz signal is, maybe there is already a guide for it.

Comment: They are square wave signals.

Comment: There are simple ways to evaluate the extra capacitance when more copper area is added to a single path. With the path impedance you can approximate the influence of an extra test-point. This would be my approach to the problem. Its a question of capacitance.

Comment: What drives those signals?  What are the edge rates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capacitance of a 2 sq mm pad (no hole) above a ground plane that is 0.3 mm lower down in the layer below (imagine a 4 layer FR4 PCB) is 0.236 pF. If the pad is double sided, that means about 0.472 pF and probably about 0.6 pF including the plated through hole.

[Parallel capacitor calculator](https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Plate-Capacitor-Calculator.phtml).

OK so a gate that gets fed the signal may have 3 pF input capacitance so, there is a degradation but not a great amount. At 1 GHz, the reactance is 265 ohms so, it does eat into tracks that are designed to be 50 ohms impedance but, not greatly.

I've used test points like this on high-speed digital signals without any noticeable problems but, make it as small as you can such as a 0.4 mm diameter PTH and maybe overall 1 sq mm surface area top and bottom. Maybe leave off the copper on the side that isn't needed for probing (to reduce capacitance a bit more) if worried.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the size and construction of the test point.

When you introduce a test point into a trace, you're adding an impedance discontinuity. That can lead to signal reflections and EMI problems.

For simple cases is possible to simulate this without too much trouble and get a rough idea for what the magnitude of the problem is likely to be.

Here's a quick worked example: imagine you've got a 140mm trace on an FR4 PCB with a dielectric constant (\$\varepsilon_r\$) of 4.6, a dielectric thickness of 0.2mm, and a copper thickness of 0.035mm. This is roughly equivalent to JLC's 7628 4-layer 1.6mm impedance controlled stackup.

Let's say we're shooting for a characteristic impedance of 50Ω, so we plug these values into a stripline impedance calculator and get 0.32mm for our trace width.

The \$\varepsilon_r\$ allows us to calculate the propagation delay on the board. Propagation velocity is given by:

$$v=\frac c {\sqrt {\varepsilon_r}}$$

where \$c\$ is the speed of light. This gives us:

$$v=\frac {3\times10^8} {\sqrt {4.6}} = 139875721ms^{-1}$$

We can use this to figure out propagation delay for a given trace length. Let's assume we're putting a testpoint right in the middle of this trace, splitting it into two 70mm lengths. Time is distance over speed, so that gives us:

$$t = \frac {0.07} {139875721} = 0.5ns$$

We can repeat this for our 1mm test point to work out what the propagation delay through it is:

$$t = \frac {0.001} {139875721} = 7.15ps$$

Now, because the test point is 1mm wide, instead of 0.32mm wide like the rest of our trace, it will have a different characteristic impedance. For simplicity, I'm assuming that the test point consists solely of a widening of the  copper trace, with no other changes (e.g. drilling). We can plug in the same parameters as before into a stripline impedance calculator, but this time using our known width (1mm) to calculate the characteristic impedance of the pad. This comes out at 22.9Ω.

Here's the resulting layout:

[image: Diagram of trace with test point]

However, this is missing one critical extra variable: the extra capacitance of the pad. Plugging the board parameters into a rectangular pad capacitance calculator tells us that the capacitance is around 0.6pF.

We can plug this into a simulation to show the behaviour with and without the test point:

[image: Circuit diagram for simulating the transmission lines]

([simulation link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjOCmC0YEzgAwDo6MXA7JgzIgHHAGwCcJmIArIlSACw5UxhgBQYmEOC8+4RNXiBqVmIwUWHtOIHPjrg4fSvEV8RYqhKkcIcOAqFK+QmpmRhRsBPuQl+UgOb9BdQwJfCns+eDc-3GiDWAHcqVSEVHlVEUPDohEp-FgRYgCcqZNUkwK9qOJzPKM9YsOKwD3L-dJBYSRTZBLzSxvBVbjUpMI6wfx6PFv6aaBJ6gdYAN1rRzxH6mJAedGXlxeRKNY2g9fYPMBIm-UMFsBh7MBXL2IqaHEom7kEIqBGkK+W4uWOEL86Wm86AIa-z2EQObVSn18DTuTViziOfgUiIBwQR+BM-mMJS6iwIIBmaD4dHUnxw9SUsnJ9FJYSJNMWmAQJNxiJmjwJkkG1JZWGZtMZ-MFDliABlhRVhUEvAAzACGABsAM6QWgtbFCDmmVgAY0agkpWoGICIzEYcDslCI+EQOEsRHucBIiDoMCIjBQ6DYziNtzQ4EwXKkAElpvMEHUIV4LiJWD6eB4eoGvPD4kUIsnggB7JAi+iIMhqixeJayVg5iiSmh0Av2LbFvQgCg4VhyKkgABiEEE4mGEAAygrICEADpKgBKcoALpAxwAKABqAHoAHZKgCUrcxna4byuWnefc7aUgAEcAK6QFc6gCerCAA))

Setting the control signal to L puts the test point in the path. Setting it to H removes it from the path.

Without the test point, everything looks clean:

[image: Graph showing the signal propagating]

There are no reflections at the transmitter and the rise time is good at the receiver.

With the test point in place, we start to see some issues:

[image: Graph showing the signal propagating with reflections and longer rise/fall times]

There are signal reflections at the transmitter side, and the rise/fall times on the receiver are slower.

This problem gets worse as the test point size increases - [here's a simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjOCmC0YEzgAwDo6MXA7JgzIgHHAGwCcJmIArIlSACw5UxhgBQYmEOC8+4RNXiBqVmIwUWHtOIHPjrg4fSvEV8RYqhKkcIcOAqFK+QwcgbMIYRmEmJWAc36C6hgc+FSncw69nyPGnsAdypVIRUeVRCwqIRKPxYEewAnKkTVBLcgrVZQrI9IwLzYwvC-VJBYSSTZOM9qEu5wVWbTJp4-NvcY7ppoEhqe1gA3KsGPAZrokB50eYXZ5EollaDl9ncwEnr9QxmwGBIkBdPNmhxKeu5BcKgBk9P5poDanzUpUNtBJQ9amO+LR4OyBn38+wQl3q9ice3AfjhgKCjlm+BMCLRgTBaD4Exx9HUTRwNV+OGJBOxBApWAQdEJoThExuIAmvXJdNmmFp9M53N5-CkABl+bZ+TkaAAzACGABsAM6QWgxYwfZntADGdR+fDVPXu4WWBCImFciGJ+EolGJyWQ6DY3jQHjVmDsUgAkuNpghqqDBOgqCi+nVwC7PDDSoCihxXfYAPZIAU0OiIMhK5AQGhzWSseMUUVJlPHODLYS2lZ6EAUHCsOSyRgAMQzCeo-QgAGUZZBggAdOUAJSlABdIL2ABQANQA9AA7OUAShr6JAjdkj1OWie-tgy5SkAAjgBXSDT9UAT1YQA) for a 2x2mm pad at 1GHz.

Keep in mind that this is a *very rough* simulation of the problem. To get more accurate numbers you really need a field solver that can simulate your exact board layout and stackup. Even then you're subject to manufacturing tolerances and other environmental factors.

As to whether or not the results of this simulation constitute a problem, the exact tolerance for reflections and slower rise/fall depends on your specific design requirements. For higher frequencies it's definitely worse, but for 100MHz you generally have a fair amount of slack.

Comment: This seems rather pessimistic to me.  What's the rise & fall time of your 100 MHz signal?  I couldn't glean that from the simulation.

Comment: Falstad doesn't have rise/fall times built into the square wave generator, but I'll update the sim to add an inverter in the driver path since that has a configurable slew rate.

Comment: @SteveSh I've updated the simulations. The slew rate defaults to 100V/ns but can be changed with the slider on the right.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Dr. Eric Bogatin, an industry recognized signal integrity expert, came up with a rule of thumb (#23) that addresses this scenario.  It states that "When the capacitance (in femtofarads) of your discontinuity is greater than 10 × risetime (in ps), the discontinuity will affect the signal."

Obviously then, with a signal edge rate of 10 ps (as some have used in simulations), there is going to be a noticeable affect on the signal.  However with a more realistic edge rate of 100 ps, you can stand an capacitance discontinuity of 1 pf without significant signal degradation.

Which brings us to a good design suggestion.  Don't make your edges any faster than they need to be.  With OP's stated 100 MHz square wave, a 100 ps rise and fall time should be plenty fast enough, and a 500 ps rise and fall time would be even more forgiving.

Comment: Good point on the rule of thumb. Dialling in a 100ps rise/fall still shows a fairly noticeable reflection in my sims, but towards 400-500ps it's far less visible.

Comment: That was my point.  There is no such thing as a ideal square wave in the real world.  So whether or not the capacitance/impedance discontinuity has an effect of the SI that OP needs to be concerned about comes down to the rise & fall times of that "square wave".